# C# Telegram bot stops working after internet disconnects

Tags: c#, telegram

I'm trying to get Telegram messages using C# API. The problem is when my internet connection breaks and then reconnects, the bot is not receiving my messages. Is there any solution for this?

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{
   var botClient = new Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient("API_KEY");
   // check if last message is newer than already processed message
   DateTime lastChecked = DateTime.Now; 
   while (true)
   {
       var listenForChanges = await botClient.GetUpdatesAsync();
       if (lastChecked < listenForChanges.Last().Message.Date)
       {
             lastChecked = DateTime.Now;
             //do something
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw exceptions? Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: No exceptions. Where I put "//do something" the program sends response to Telegram but in this case it looks like the program is running without exceptions but it doesn't send messages so I guess also not receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Standard Library for Create You Bot

Try this [Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/)

In this Library You can Create You bot With GetUpdate Or Webhook Method
You can Create Your Bot On MVC Project

Check This: [Example Code](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples)